# Is it possible to nested form in one view in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view where a form is already exist. Now I added one more form inside that form when I submit inside form I couldn't get any values from the inside form. Here is my code snippet.

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Details", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "OrderDetailsForm" }); %>
...
    <% Html.BeginForm("AddPickupIssue", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "pickupIssueForm" }); %>
    ...
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
    ...
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Is it right way to do it? Please guide me here.

TIA

Comment: You are using Mvc 4 but no Razor?

Comment: How about creating a pratial view and add a form in partial view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nested forms aren't permitted in HTML, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.  Looking at [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element), it says that `form` elements may contain "no `form` element descendants."

This makes sense, because if a `form` contained nested `form` elements, which one is being submitted and which values are submitted with it?

So, no, this is not the right way to do it.  You're going to have to re-think what you're trying to accomplish here.